# How to detect numbers from one column in another and write data from another column in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I'm very new at R language. I tried to make simple code to find some data in different intervals with information about start-end of interval and table with bigger intervals for now, I got several codes for solving but none of them work.

The main idea is that I have several variables which represent different arrays (i,k,j). Code, in my opinion, should look for each array in another table for two things (if it bigger than the first column and if it smaller then second, if both true - right all this to another table and go to other intervals).

```
if(mydatatable[k,21]>=mydatatable[i,16]){
    if(mydatatable[k,21]<=mydatatable[j,18]) 
        shifr[n,1]<-n&shifr[n,2]<-mydata[k,21]&shifr[n,3]<-mydata[k,22]&i+1&j+1&k+1&n+1 
    else i+1&j+1&k+1
} 
else {
    if(mydatatable[i,16]==0) end 
    else i+1&j+1&k+1
    }
```

for this code several errors 
Error in if (mydatatable[k, 21] >= mydatatable[i, 16]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(mydatatable[k, 21], mydatatable[i, 16]) :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
I wonder, why programm thinks, that mydatatable is factor? Why it should be some TRUE/FALSE value, I thought, that it was already established in formula.
The second code is pretty much the same and it even might work.
I preestablished the values i,k and j as 1 (i=1, k=1, j=1)
But there comes a error

```
> ifelse(mydatatable[k,21]>=mydatatable[i,16],
+        ifelse(mydatatable[k,21]<=mydatatable[j,18],
+               shifr[n,1]<-n&shifr[n,2]<-mydata[k,21]&shifr[n,3]<-mydata[k,22]&i+1&j+1&k+1&n+1,i+1&j+1&k+1),
+        ifelse(mydatatable[i,16]==0,
+               end),
+        i+1&j+1&k+1)
Error in ifelse(mydatatable[k, 21] >= mydatatable[i, 16], ifelse(mydatatable[k,  : 
  unused argument (i + 1 & j + 1 & k + 1)
```

I'm confused, why it's happening.
Please, help.

Here is an example of data. What I want to get is demonstrated here https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj4W4aYSeYkGiIFKHG0TV-TRQvWaIQ

Here what I got, after several use of data.table::foverlaps (I fixed some problems, but initially I got this)

```
> data.table::foverlaps(int1,sh2,by.x=c("start","end"),by.y=c("start","end"))
Error in data.table::foverlaps(int1, sh2, by.x = c("start", "end"), by.y = c("start",  : 
  The first 2 columns of y's key is not identical to the columns specified in by.y.
```

I have also got some progress with previous code. Several problems: first, how to unite several commands  (I used & and ; but none of them worked properly in `shifr[n,1]<-n;shifr[n,2]<-sh[k,1];shifr[n,3]<-sh[k,1];i+1&j+`?)
Second, is about Error in FUN(left, right).

```
> ifelse(sh[k,1]>=int[i,1],
+        +        ifelse(sh[k,2]<=int[j,2],
+                        +               shifr[n,1]<-n;shifr[n,2]<-sh[k,1];shifr[n,3]<-sh[k,1];i+1;j+1;k+1;n+1,i+1;j+1;k+1),
Error: unexpected ';' in:
"       +        ifelse(sh[k,2]<=int[j,2],
                       +               shifr[n,1]<-n;"
>        +        i+1;j+1;k+1
[1] 16
[1] 16
[1] 65
> ifelse(sh[k,1]>=int[i,1],
+        +        ifelse(sh[k,2]<=int[j,2],
+                        +               shifr[n,1]<-n;shifr[n,2]<-sh[k,1];shifr[n,3]<-sh[k,1];i+1&j+1&k+1&n+1,i+1&j+1&k+1),
Error: unexpected ';' in:
"       +        ifelse(sh[k,2]<=int[j,2],
                       +               shifr[n,1]<-n;"
>        +        i+1&j+1&k+1
[1] TRUE
> ifelse(sh[k,1]>=int[i,1],
+        +        ifelse(sh[k,2]<=int[j,2],
+                        +               shifr[n,1]<-n&shifr[n,2]<-sh[k,1]&shifr[n,3]<-sh[k,1]&i+1&j+1&k+1&n+1,i+1&j+1&k+1),
+        +        i+1&j+1&k+1
+ )
Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: Are you trying to do an overlap join? I can't open your links, but if you are, check out `data.table::foverlaps`.

Comment: It is not like overlapping. I need to get information from the interval, which is meant to be in two columns. Here is another demonstration https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj4W4aYSeYkGiIFKHG0TV-TRQvWaIQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is, actually, awful. I eventually done it like that(in python):

```
for i in interval:
...
     if float(i) < intervals[b][0]:
                    print("Interval are too high", intervals[b][1])
                    break
....    
                if float(i) >= intervals[b - 1][1]:
....
```